# style.css does not load correctly

Tags: codeigniter

This is my code.  I wonder why the style sheet does not load up correctly?

admin/views/login.php

```
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

 <title>CodePen - Log-in</title>

 <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery-ui.css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>assets/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>


<?php $this->load->library('form_validation'); ?>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('cpages/ceklogin'); ?>

<div class="login-card">

<center><?php //echo $warning; ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('warning'); ?>  
</center>
<h2>Gionda CMS Login</h2><br>
<form>
<div class="login"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"></div>
<div class="login"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login">
</form>

<div class="login-help">
<a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
</div>
</div>

<!-- <div id="error"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23299152/Delete-icon.png" /> Your caps-lock is on.</div> -->

<script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery_and_jqueryui.js'></script>
```

admin/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/masterlinkci2/admin/';
```

Comment: If you go to `http://localhost/masterlinkci2/admin/assets/style.css` in your browser do you see the file contents?

Answer (score 0):

1.Load `url` helper in `application/config/autoload.php`.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

2.Then set `base_url` to url as your root folder.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/masterlinkci2/';
```

3.And link your `css` like this.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/style.css');?>" media="screen" type="text/css" />
```

Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to add the path into your **baseurl** function parameters and not by *appending* path to it.

```
<?php echo base_url('') ?>
```

Instead use the following to add css:

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/style.css') ?>
```